# django multiple random questions with same answer options

Tags: django, modelform

Have this small app with a model for questions and their answers are picked from a tuple.
My current challenge is to display the questions with a dropdown for the answers using a modelform. Once submitted the form should save noting the question id and answer option selected.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_options = [
        ('EM', 'Exceeded Expectations'),
        ('ME', 'Met Expectations'),
        ('BE', 'Below Expectations'),
    ]

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, blank=True, Null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    answer_selected = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=answer_options, default='ME')
```

**Edits Below:**

forms.py

```
QuestionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = '__all__'
```

questionsform.html

```
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'questions:q-form' %}">
{{ csrf_token }}
{{ form.as_p }}
<hr>
<button type='submit' class='button button-secondary'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The form layout *should be* as follows, listing all questions and below each question are the options:

Question 1
Answer option dropdown

Question 2
Answer option dropdown

However, in the current setup as per my form the question is a dropdown just like the answer option.

Kindly assist

Comment: Your models look good, think we need to see your modelform and view/html so we can answer the question.

Comment: Well your forms are correct without and flaw . Make sure you are providing instance , request.POST in the form in the view . Can we have the look at your views and templates .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After plenty of googling found a good answer from this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/bljz4w/how_to_create_forms_with_different_number_of/) and with a little tweaking got the job done.
Hope it helps someone in a similar predicament